# Efficiently create a list of factors of consecutive integers

Tags: algorithm, number-theory, factorization

I'm interested in a scalable (read: sublinear) algorithm for producing the list of integer factors of each integer from `1` to `n`. Note that I'm not necessarily asking about a sublinear factoring algorithm.

Using the built-in `FactorInteger`, I get the following timings for powers of ten up to `10^7`:

```
Table[{j, First@Timing[Table[FactorInteger@i, {i, 1, 10^j}];]}, {j, 1, 7}]

(*{{1, 0.000039}, {2, 0.000255}, {3, 0.003083}, {4, 0.036405}, {5, 0.344576}, {6, 3.84674}, {7, 68.0302}}*)
```

This is more or less linear up through `10^6`, but gets pretty bad at `10^7`. One would think that it would be faster to build up a list of factorizations using the list of primes. Here is one attempt at doing so:

```
Table[{k, First@Timing[lim = 10^k;
  lst = Table[{}, lim];
  addprime[p_] := 
   Do[AppendTo[lst[[i p]], {p, IntegerExponent[i p, p]}], {i, 1, 
     Floor[lim/p]}];
  Do[addprime[Prime@p], {p, PrimePi[lim]}];]}, {k, 1, 7}]

(*{{1, 0.549175}, {2, 0.000767}, {3, 0.009434}, {4, 0.093252}, {5, 1.05787}, {6, 12.5425}, {7, 154.35}}*)
```

(For each prime, put the appropriate power of that prime at each slot in the results table.)

This is also close to linear, but consistently slower than the `FactorInteger` approach.

Perhaps I'm looking for something I can't have; the process of building up the required arrays may be inherently linear. Does anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: Note that trial division will eventually become prohibitively expensive as your integers grow larger. `FactorInteger[]` supplements trial division with fanicer factoring methods (e.g. Pollard), so I'm pessimistic that you can outdo `FactorInteger[]` in this case.

Comment: @J.M. I am not doing trial division, unless that's what IntegerExponent does.

Comment: It looks equivalent to me, since you're only appending primes if they are factors of your number.

Comment: @J.M. Note that I'm not just trying to factor `n`; I'm generating a factor list for all integers below `n`. So while there might be something equivalent to trial division going on here, it is happening for all n integers at once.

Answer (score 1):

I have never been able to beat `FactorInteger`, but I was able to approximately double the speed of your code by using the following.

```
Block[{lim, v, r},
   Table[{k,
      First@AbsoluteTiming[
      lim = 10^k;
      v = ConstantArray[{}, lim];
      Do[
         r = p*Range[Floor[lim/p]];
         v[[r]] = Join[v[[r]], Map[{{p, #}} &, IntegerExponent[r, p]], 2],
      {p, Prime[Range[PrimePi[lim]]]}];
      v]},
   {k, 1, 7}]]
```